Issues with the RESOLVE Ecoregions 2017 dataset
I'm new in GEE and I'm trying to visualize the biomes on a specific area of America. I'm having trouble visualizing the 15 biomes and doing it for this specific area only. How could I visualize this without any memory exceed problem (That's the error im getting).
Once I'm done with that, how could I export that to raster?
I just modified the original code that the Dataset gives you, and I'm not sure if im missing something:
    var ecoRegions = ee.FeatureCollection('RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017');

 patch updated colors
var colorUpdates = [
{BIOME_NUM: 1, COLOR: '#B3493B'},
{BIOME_NUM: 2, COLOR: '#267400'},
{BIOME_NUM: 3, COLOR: '#004600'},
{BIOME_NUM: 4, COLOR: '#82F178'},
{BIOME_NUM: 5, COLOR: '#E600AA'},
{BIOME_NUM: 6, COLOR: '#5AA500'},
{BIOME_NUM: 7, COLOR: '#FDA87F'},
{BIOME_NUM: 8, COLOR: '#A93800'},
{BIOME_NUM: 9, COLOR: '#2FDDE0'},
{BIOME_NUM: 10, COLOR: '#E4FF00'},
{BIOME_NUM: 11, COLOR: '#AD228E'},
{BIOME_NUM: 12, COLOR: '#37D111'},
{BIOME_NUM: 13, COLOR: '#11C2D1'},
{BIOME_NUM: 14, COLOR: '#3D11D1'},
];

// loop over all other features and create a new style property for styling
// later on
var ecoRegions = ecoRegions.map(function(f) {
  var color = f.get('COLOR');
  return f.set({style: {color: color, width: 0}});
});

// make styled features for the regions we need to update colors for,
// then strip them from the main asset and merge in the new feature
for (var i=0; i < colorUpdates.length; i++) {
  colorUpdates[i].layer = ecoRegions
      .filterMetadata('BIOME_NUM','equals',colorUpdates[i].BIOME_NUM)
      .map(function(f) {
        return f.set({style: {color: colorUpdates[i].COLOR, width: 0}});
      });

  ecoRegions = ecoRegions
      .filterMetadata('BIOME_NUM','not_equals',colorUpdates[i].BIOME_NUM)
      .merge(colorUpdates[i].layer)
      
}

// use style property to color shapes
var imageRGB = ecoRegions.style({styleProperty: 'style'});

Map.setCenter(16, 49, 4);
Map.addLayer(imageRGB, {}, 'RESOLVE/ECOREGIONS/2017');

